# How to make a new df from random subset of rows from another df without duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matrix

How do you make a new dataframe from a  select number of random rows from another dataframe? I'd like it to be without duplicates if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it; replace N with your desired number of rows.

```
subset_df = df.sample(N)
```